# Como enviar datos sin conexión android

Tags: java, android-studio, mariadb

quiero que mi app envía datos a mariaDB pero que cuando el usuario no tenga conexión de internet la aplicación siga funcionando y cunado la aplicación detecte una conexión de internet automáticamente envié los datos a mi base de datos.

Comment: eso va para investigación propia en primer lugar, luego cuando tengas algo a medio camino, con mucho gusto te ayudamos a completarlo :D aquí tienes unos tutoriales de android: http://www.tutorialesprogramacionya.com/javaya/androidya/ - https://www.tutorialspoint.com/android/index.htm te sugiero aprender también sobre servicios REST y SQLite para mantener los datos en una Base de datos local. Saludos

Answer (score 2):

Debes almacenar los datos en la Base de Datos interna del Telefono (SQLite) luego consultar si existen registros de ser asi debes validar que se disponga de una conexion a internet y finalmente hacer la llamada a tu web Service

```
public static boolean compruebaConexion(Context context)
{
    boolean connected = false;
    ConnectivityManager connec = (ConnectivityManager) context.getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);

    // Recupera todas las redes (tanto móviles como wifi)
    NetworkInfo[] redes = connec.getAllNetworkInfo();

    for (int i = 0; i < redes.length; i++) {
        // Si alguna red tiene conexión, se devuelve true
        if (redes[i].getState() == NetworkInfo.State.CONNECTED) {
            connected = true;
        }
    }
    return connected;
}
```

Espero te sirva
Saludos.